# how to save the token returned by server in my angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, api

I am using API to authenticate user and login but I don't know how to save the token returned by the server for future authentication . The object being returned holds the token .

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {ServerService} from '../server.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private req: ServerService) { }
  token = 'no';

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.req.requestLogin({'email': form.value.email,
    'password': form.value.password})
      .subscribe(
        (response) => this.token = response.token, // ERROR
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }

}
```

the error shown is Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: What the output of console.log(response) ?

Comment: One problem seems to be that your ServerService is returning a type `object`, so it doesn't expect a property `token` to exist. If you gave a return type of `{ token: string }` or an equivalent type, then that error should disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try following code.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import {ServerService} from '../server.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private req: ServerService) { }
  token = 'no';

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    this.req.requestLogin({'email': form.value.email,
    'password': form.value.password})
      .subscribe(
        (response) => this.token = response['token'], // ERROR
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }

}
```

**Edit 1-**

> Only replace response.token by response['token']